# Razor custom error page ignores it's OnGet handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

There is custom error page:

```
public sealed class ErrorModel : PageModel
{
    public ErrorModel()
    {
       // app stops at breakpoint inside ctor
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        // app doesn't stop here, why?

        // this is for debugging purposes only
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

and its view:

```
@page
@model ErrorModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    <p>
        The error page.
    </p>
}
```

Page is registered in usual way:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
```

When application redirects to error page, it stops on breakpoints inside page constructor and page view, but ignores code inside `OnGet`. Since app doesn't call my `OnGet`, page renders without any useful data I fill inside `OnGet`.

All breakpoints are enabled - I'm debugging actual code.

Any idea what's happening and how to solve this?

**UPD**

I've reduced the page model code and the view.
When app stops at this line:

`@if (Model != null)`

the call stack is:

> Portal.App.Views.dll!Portal.Pages.Pages_Error.ExecuteAsync() Line 4 C#
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.RazorPageAdapter.ExecuteAsync()  Unknown
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorPage page, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext context) Unknown
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorPage page, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)  Unknown
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext context) Unknown
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, int? statusCode)  Unknown
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageContext pageContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult result)  Unknown
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.ExecuteResultAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext context)   Unknown

So, app executes `PageResult`. Where this result comes from?

**UPD 2**

This looks like authentication issue. When user is authenticated, everything works as expected. But for non-authenticated users my `OnGet` isn't called. `ErrorModel` hasn't `Authorize` attribute. How authentication affects this?

I've no any custom authentication config, so, I assume defaults are used:

```
    private void ConfigureMvcServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc()
            // another services;
    }
```

Error page is in the `Pages` folder - `Pages/Error`.

Besides, if user is not authenticated, and page requires authentication, 401 must be returned, isn't it?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills: How? There's noting exotic inside this page. Just add error page into razor page app project. But I'm sure you won't reproduce this issue. I'm trying to understand, how app calls page model ctor and view code, but doesn't call OnGet.

Comment: What version of .NET Core are you targeting?

Comment: @MindSwipe: it's 2.2 version.

Comment: Have you tried to add `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` to the razor page?

Comment: @rpfc: there's _ViewImports with this code. Actually, I've reduced the page model code and the view (question is updated). Still no luck.

Comment: Is your Error page in a folder that's protected by the `AuthorizeFolder` method in `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: @MikeBrind: in short, no. Updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out. The pitfall is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#exception-handler-page):

> To configure a custom error handling page for the Production
>   environment, use the Exception Handling Middleware. The middleware:
>
> - Catches and logs exceptions.
> - **Re-executes the request in an alternate pipeline for the page or controller indicated. The request isn't re-executed if the response
>     has started.**

"Re-executes" means, literally, that if exception was raised in GET handler, middleware calls error page's OnGet. If it was raised in POST handler, middleware calls OnPost, etc:

```
public class ErrorModel : PageModel
{
    public ErrorModel()
    {
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        // This executes when exception was in OnGet
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        // This executes when exception was in OnPost
    }

    // ...
}
```

In my case there was a GET request on page with authentication, and POST one on non-authenticated page, so here's the difference in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled custom errors in the web config. Like this:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```